# Allow future users of docker image to install packages

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I wish to create a docker image which runs pytest and generates coverage report based on SLES15.
I also provide a shell script which mounts the host's pwd and starts the container with the user's id so that the generated reports are not owned by the root.
(There's also a script which creates a virtual env on the host and install the requirements.txt)

```bash
docker run --rm -e PYTHONPATH=${VENVPATH} -v ${PWD}:${PWD} -w ${PWD} --user $(id -u):$(id -g) pythoncoverage pytest
```

Now, there are users whos projects needs OS packages to be installed (eg: libxml or pango).

I want them to be able to run `zypper install pango` even the container is started with their user id on the host. (So it can be anything, I can't create all possible users during image build. I also don't know what packages might be required in the future to install during build.)

I tried setting the SUID bit on zypper, and I get this error:

```bash
(28/39) Installing: libX11-6-1.6.5-150000.3.24.1.x86_64 .......................[done]
/bin/sh: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.svxwpq: Permission denied error: %prein(shadow-4.8.1-150400.8.57.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 126 
error: shadow-4.8.1-150400.8.57.x86_64: install failed 
29/39) Installing: shadow-4.8.1-150400.8.57.x86_64 .......................[error] 
Installation of shadow-4.8.1-150400.8.57.x86_64 failed: Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: Command exited with status 1
```

Exit code 126 stands for "Command not executable",  it seems that the SUID bit in itself is not enough.

I then tried adding all users to the /etc/sudoers without requiring password, but then when `sudo zypper` is called the error is:

```bash
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
```

So in summary, I'm looking for a way to make all possible future users able to run zypper to intall their dependencies inside the container.

Comment: In their derived Dockerfiles, they can switch to `USER root`.  You don't need to do anything special to support that.

Comment: @DavidMaze They don't have a derived image, they are supposed to use the wrapper script. (That also has to be extended to accept new arguments, what dependencies to install before running pytest.)